# Yom Haatzmaut on Calendar?

Tags: feature-request, events

It seems that the site calendar (upcoming events) does not include holidays such as Yom Haatzmaut and Yom Yerushalaim.  Would it be possible to add them, so users can easily see posts about them at times like this?

Comment: That was an oversight this year; I'm pretty sure we had יום העצמאות last year. Each event must be added individually, so some are missed.

Comment: Not every Jew is a Zionist, and this site is not necessarily in agreement or disagreement. I think we ought to keep things neutral when it comes to this subject.

Comment: @ezra I was more thinking that the purpose of the events section is often to provide material from Mi Yodeya on it.  Being that we have questions (and a tag) about Yom Haatzmaut, I think it would be appropriate to post even if we are neutral.

Comment: @ezra every Jew who prays the amida three times a day is a Zionist since he prays for kibbutz galuyot and the rebuilding of Jerusalem :-> But I know what you mean. This being said, the calendar is called "Upcoming events". Whether you observe them or not, a large portion of am Israel does, so they become relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing the Community Events lately. There are various special days I don't tend to do them for, such as Rosh Chodesh, T"U Bishevat, and minor fasts. I don't choose what to put up based on a formal rule (so far), but it's basically *parashat hashavua'* and major holidays that we have lots of material on.

Yom Ha'atzma'ut is a major holiday for many Jews, it's not a holiday at all for many Jews, and it's a minor observance for many Jews. Our tag for it, [yom-haatzmaut](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-haatzmaut), has only 19 questions so far. So, I'm not sure whether it's worthwhile to put up a Community Event for it or not. Yom Yerushalayim is a major holiday for fewer Jews than Yom Ha'atzma'ut is, and our tag for it, [yom-yerushalayom-yerushalayim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-yerushalayom-yerushalayim), has only 9 questions so far.

To make this into a votable answer: status quo is that I don't bother with Y"H or Y"Y until such time as their tags become richer sources of material.

Alternative answers are welcome. I'll be happy to follow the will of the community.

Comment: While I wouldn't wish to burden you, I think that the more the merrier. I'm my opinion, even a calendar event for an obscure holiday or former fast would be useful if we have material on it. Think of Yat Shvat ;)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות consider writing an answer. Yat Shevat is of particular local interest - "שעשה *לי* נס במקום הזה".

Comment: Perhaps the opposite is true: by adding them to the calendar and emphasizing their importance on the site, more questions will be posted about them. Can someone do a search over time of how the questions spike for the weekly parsha before and after community events was instituted?

Comment: @DonielF The actual seasonality of these events confounds that sort of analysis.

Comment: @IsaacMoses So then compare to the Yomim Tovim. Of course there will be a spike at those times of year. I’m curious if the spike is bigger now that we have community events. I’d run the analysis myself but I can never figure out how that thing works, nor do I know when community events was added.